# I can't access timeline in main.js, timeline initialize in the file anim.js

Tags: javascript, html, create.js

Hello everyone I have such a problem. I have two scripts, anim.js and main.js . In anim.js describes the animation, and in main.js I'm trying to make a stop by pressing a button. I'm trying to make a stop through timeline, but I can't access timeline in main.js, timeline initialize in the file anim.js

anim.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="Adobe_Animate_CC" name="authoring-tool">
    <title>anim</title>
    <!-- write your code here -->
    <style>
        #animation_container {
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        body, canvas {
            background: none transparent !important;
        }
    </style>


    <script src="../js/libs/adobe/createjs.js"></script>
    <script src="anim.js"></script>

    <script>
        var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;

        function init() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
            dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
            var comp = AdobeAn.getComposition("4D38855BFA773041952A1579DB0CC3CC");
            var lib = comp.getLibrary();
            var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
            loader.addEventListener("fileload", function (evt) {
                handleFileLoad(evt, comp)
            });
            loader.addEventListener("complete", function (evt) {
                handleComplete(evt, comp)
            });
            var lib = comp.getLibrary();
            loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
        }

        function handleFileLoad(evt, comp) {
            var images = comp.getImages();
            if (evt && (evt.item.type == "image")) {
                images[evt.item.id] = evt.result;
            }
        }

        function handleComplete(evt, comp) {
            //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created
            //in token create_stage.
            var lib = comp.getLibrary();
            var ss = comp.getSpriteSheet();
            var queue = evt.target;
            var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
            for (i = 0; i < ssMetadata.length; i++) {
                ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
                    "images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)],
                    "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames
                })
            }
            exportRoot = new lib.anim();
            stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);
            //Registers the "tick" event listener.
            fnStartAnimation = function () {
                stage.addChild(exportRoot);
                createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
                createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
            };
            //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
            AdobeAn.makeResponsive(true, 'both', true, 1, [canvas, anim_container, dom_overlay_container]);
            AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
            fnStartAnimation();

        }
    </script>
    <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        function doLoadIframe() {
            console.log('catch1');
            let msg = function() {
                p = 'привет';
                return p;
            }
            //отправка события родителю
            parent.postMessage(msg(), '*');
            parent.focus();

            init();
            //setTimeout(stpAnimDef, 100);
        }

    </script>

    <script>

        window.addEventListener("message", function(msg){
            console.log(msg.data);
            if (msg.data == 'stop') {
                stopAnimation();
            } else if (msg.data == 'play'){
                playAnimation();
            }

            let text = document.querySelector('.textAnim');
            text.value = msg.data;

        });

    </script>


    <!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="doLoadIframe();" style="margin:0px;">
<div id="animation_container" style="width:1280px; height:720px">
    <canvas height="720" id="canvas"
            style="position: absolute; display: block;"
            width="1280"></canvas>
    <div id="dom_overlay_container"
         style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:1280px; height:720px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>

<input type='text' class='textAnim' />


</body>

</html>
```

anim.js

```
var timeline = new createjs.Timeline({paused: true});

(function (cjs, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [
        {name:"anim_atlas_", frames: [[0,0,233,233]]}
];

// symbols:

(lib.CachedTexturedBitmap_1 = function() {
    this.initialize(ss["anim_atlas_"]);
    this.gotoAndStop(0);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }


(lib.Символ1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Слой_1
    this.instance = new lib.CachedTexturedBitmap_1();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5);

    var t = cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1);

    timeline.addTween(t/*cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1)*/);

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Символ1, new cjs.Rectangle(-0.5,-0.5,116.5,116.5), null);


// stage content:
(lib.anim = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Слой_1
    this.instance = new lib.Символ1();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(210.85,268.85,1,1,0,0,0,57.8,57.8);

    var t1 = cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1).to({x:243.8},0).wait(1).to({x:276.8},0).wait(1).to({x:309.8},0).wait(1).to({x:342.8},0).wait(1).to({x:375.8},0).wait(1).to({x:408.8},0).wait(1).to({x:441.8},0).wait(1).to({x:474.8},0).wait(1).to({x:507.8},0).wait(1).to({x:540.8},0).wait(1).to({x:573.8},0).wait(1).to({x:606.8},0).wait(1).to({x:639.8},0).wait(1).to({x:672.8},0).wait(1).to({x:705.75},0).wait(1).to({x:738.75},0).wait(1).to({x:771.75},0).wait(1).to({x:804.75},0).wait(1).to({x:837.75},0).wait(1).to({x:870.75},0).wait(1).to({x:903.75},0).wait(1).to({x:936.75},0).wait(1).to({x:969.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1002.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1035.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1068.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1101.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1134.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1167.75},0).wait(1)
        .call(function(){
            this.dispatchEvent("foo");
        }, null, timeline);

    timeline.addTween(t1);
    timeline.setPaused(false);
    //this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance, {reversed:true})./*wait(1).to({x:243.8},0).wait(1).to({x:276.8},0).wait(1).to({x:309.8},0).wait(1).to({x:342.8},0).wait(1).to({x:375.8},0).wait(1).to({x:408.8},0).wait(1).to({x:441.8},0).wait(1).to({x:474.8},0).wait(1).to({x:507.8},0).*/wait(1).to({x:540.8},0).wait(1).to({x:573.8},0).wait(1).to({x:606.8},0).wait(1).to({x:639.8},0).wait(1).to({x:672.8},0).wait(1).to({x:705.75},0).wait(1).to({x:738.75},0).wait(1).to({x:771.75},0).wait(1).to({x:804.75},0).wait(1).to({x:837.75},0).wait(1).to({x:870.75},0).wait(1).to({x:903.75},0).wait(1).to({x:936.75},0).wait(1).to({x:969.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1002.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1035.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1068.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1101.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1134.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1167.75},0).wait(1));

    //this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1).to({x:540.8},0).wait(1).to({x:573.8},0).wait(1).to({x:606.8},0).wait(1).to({x:639.8},0).wait(1).to({x:672.8},0).wait(1).to({x:705.75},0).wait(1).to({x:738.75},0).wait(1).to({x:771.75},0).wait(1).to({x:804.75},0).wait(1).to({x:837.75},0).wait(1).to({x:870.75},0).wait(1).to({x:903.75},0).wait(1).to({x:936.75},0).wait(1).to({x:969.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1002.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1035.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1068.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1101.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1134.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1167.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1134.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1101.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1068.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1035.75},0).wait(1).to({x:1002.75},0).wait(1).to({x:969.75},0).wait(1).to({x:936.75},0).wait(1).to({x:903.75},0).wait(1).to({x:870.75},0).wait(1).to({x:837.75},0).wait(1).to({x:804.75},0).wait(1).to({x:771.75},0).wait(1).to({x:738.75},0).wait(1).to({x:705.75},0).wait(1).to({x:672.8},0).wait(1).to({x:639.8},0).wait(1).to({x:606.8},0).wait(1).to({x:573.8},0).wait(1).to({x:540.8},0).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();

p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(792.6,570.6,433.30000000000007,-243.5);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '4D38855BFA773041952A1579DB0CC3CC',
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    fps: 20,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    opacity: 1.00,
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/anim_atlas_.png", id:"anim_atlas_"}
    ],
    preloads: []
};



// bootstrap callback support:

(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
    createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();

p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
    this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
    an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}

an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
    an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
    if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
            fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
        }
    }
};

an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['4D38855BFA773041952A1579DB0CC3CC'] = {
    getStage: function() { return exportRoot.getStage(); },
    getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
    getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
    getImages: function() { return img; }
};

an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
    an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
    for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
        an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
    }
}

an.getComposition = function(id) {
    return an.compositions[id];
}


an.makeResponsive = function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType, domContainers) {      
    var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
    resizeCanvas();     
    function resizeCanvas() {           
        var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
        var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
        var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
        if(isResp) {                
            if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                sRatio = lastS;                
            }               
            else if(!isScale) {                 
                if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }               
            else if(scaleType==1) {                 
                sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }               
            else if(scaleType==2) {                 
                sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }           
        }           
        domContainers[0].width = w * pRatio * sRatio;           
        domContainers[0].height = h * pRatio * sRatio;          
        domContainers.forEach(function(container) {             
            container.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';              
            container.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';         
        });         
        stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
        stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;           
        lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
        stage.update();            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
    }
}


})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
```

main.js

```
        function stopAnimation() {
         console.log(timeline);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste you all script to bottom of body htm tag